# How to use git-submodule to track feature branches?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have currently almost 20 java repositories in my Source Control. They all have different build plans but they are all built with similar strategy. I am thinking of to use `git-submodule` to have all the 20 repos as part of a single repository with single build plan. But looks-like gitsubmodule can track only one branch in `.gitsubmodule`.

```
[submodule "demo-1"]
    path = ""
    url = https://github.com/hsdajsd/demo-1.git
    branch = master
[submodule "demo-2"]
    path = ""
    url = https://github.com/hsdajsd/demo-2.git
    branch = master
```

How can I configure `gitsubmodules` to track all the branches in a submodule(including mainline and feature branches). Any suggestions from the community? Idea is to trigger the single build plan whenever any changes happens in any of the repositories regardless of branches.

Answer (score 1):

Submodules are meant to allow for closely related code to live together short of a module solution like config.json, Maven, or Gradle.  Not only do you not want to use a submodule to configure common build plans, submodules are actually fairly poor at handling that, as you only have context or reference into one commit at any given time.

You would want to look into another approach.  Depending on your language, build and project structuring tools exist to assist more with your endeavors.